# Trying to separate whole number and decimal asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm looking for guidance can someone help me out?

I need to separate the value in duration into a whole number and the decimal.

EDIT: I have a textbox in one page.  If someone enters 1.5 and it gets stored in duration, I would like to retrieve that in another page and I would like to store the whole number in a textbox and the decimal number will select a value from a dropdownlist based on the response.

Sorry I added duration twice by accident.

```
context.Response.Write(dr["Title"].ToString()
    + '|' + dr["CourseId"].ToString() + '|' + dr["duration"].ToString()
 + '|' + dr["Code"].ToString() + '|'
    + dr["Category"].ToString() + School.NewLine);
```

Comment: Huh? Do you mean you want to take a decimal number and separate the decimal and whole number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var duration = dr["duration"].ToString().Split(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator);
int durationWhole = Int32.Parse(duration[0]);
int durationDecimal = Int32.Parse(duration[1]);
```

Duration will be a string array. duration[0] is the part of the number before the decimal, and duration[1] is the part after.

The split is being done with the decimal separator of the culture using it, so it should work globally as well.

Based on the edit in your question, I've updated the answer to give you numerical results as well. Now you can use the numbers or strings as needed.

Comment: This will work where the culture is `en` anyway. If the application is global, or in another country, then it's probably best to use [NumberDecimalSeparator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator.aspx).

Comment: Good call. I was in the process of updating my answer to include that when I got called away by work.

Comment: I'm getting a error when I put this in. CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator    The name cultureinfo does not exist in the current content.

Comment: You need to include System.Globalization to your list of usings.

Answer (score 8):

If the value you are trying to split is a number, try this:

```
decimal number = 12.34;
int wholePart = decimal.Truncate(number);
decimal fractionPart = number - wholePart;
```

If is is a string, CLandry's answer should work, duration[0] would be the whole part and duration[1] would be the fraction part.

Comment: Good info. I didn't feel comfortable giving that info in my answer since I couldn't tell the type of duration from the question. Felt safer to treat it as a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
context.Response.Write(dr["Title"].ToString()
    + '|' + dr["CourseId"].ToString() + '|' + dr["duration"].ToString().Split('.')[0]
    + '|' + dr["duration"].ToString().Split('.')[1] + '|' + dr["Code"].ToString() + '|'
    + dr["Category"].ToString() + School.NewLine);
```

Comment: I wouldn't go through splitting the string twice. It's easier to split it once and then use the individual parts. You also don't account for global use since not all countries use the period as the decimal separator.

Comment: I'm getting this error.         Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Substrings and IndexOf:

```
{ context.Response.Write(
    dr["Title"].ToString() + '|' + 
    dr["CourseId"].ToString() + '|' + 
    dr["duration"].ToString().Substring(0, dr["duration"].ToString().IndexOf(".")) + '|' + 
    dr["duration"].ToString().Substring(dr["duration"].ToString().IndexOf("."), dr["duration"].ToString().Length()) + '|' + 
    dr["Code"].ToString() + '|' + 
    dr["Category"].ToString() + 
    School.NewLine);
}
```